# Opengrok indexing failure

Tags: tomcat, ctags, opengrok

I have gone through so many posts and articles , but not able to find the solution.
I am facing the problem when creating index.

Error :-

```
-bash-3.2$ ./OpenGrok index
Loading the default instance configuration ...
12:01:17 SEVERE: An error occurred while parsing the xml output
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -6
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1875)
    at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.SubversionHistoryParser$Handler.endElement(SubversionHistoryParser.java:99)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1742)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2900)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:302)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.SubversionHistoryParser.processStream(SubversionHistoryParser.java:182)
    at org.opensolaris.opengrok.util.Executor.exec(Executor.java:151)
    at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.SubversionHistoryParser.parse(SubversionHistoryParser.java:154)
    at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.SubversionRepository.getHistory(SubversionRepository.java:238)
    at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.Repository.createCache(Repository.java:286)
    at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.HistoryGuru.createCache(HistoryGuru.java:478)
    at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.HistoryGuru.access$000(HistoryGuru.java:51)
    at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.HistoryGuru$1.run(HistoryGuru.java:522)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I am using UNIX OS. I have already installed ctags,tomcat7 and opengrok-0.12 and its running . I am able to access from browser.

But , when I am trying to create the index it failed.

1. How can I check that index has created or not ?

Let me know if any other information required.

Please suggest , if I missed some thing.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the data directory (e.g. /var/opengrok/data) and running index again. I have noticed some strange behavior when interrupting the indexing process and rerunning.
Also try running index as root and see if it still complains.